# Magento2 controller_action_predispatch not working with Varnish enabled

Tags: magento2, php, varnish, docker

I am using Magento version 2.3
Varnish 6 enabled
Docker setup

I am implementing force login on event 'controller_action_predispatch'. Below is my code:

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="kernel_request_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\FrontSendResponseBefore" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/FrontSendResponseBefore.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class FrontSendResponseBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $_helper;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
    */
    protected $redirect;

    private $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\CoreHelper $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        $allowedUrls = array(
            'customer_account_login', 
            'customer_account_loginPost',
            'customer_account_logout', 
            'customer_account_logoutSuccess',
            'customer_account_forgotpassword',
            'customer_account_forgotpasswordpost',
            'customer_account_createPassword', 
            'customer_account_createpassword',
            'customer_account_resetpasswordpost'
        );

        $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();

        $redirect = true;
        if (!$this->ifForceLoginEnabledForStore()) {
            $redirect = false;
        } else if (in_array($actionName, $allowedUrls)) {
            $redirect = false;
        } elseif ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $redirect = false;
        }

        echo 4; die;

        if ($redirect) {
            $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
        }
    }

    private function ifForceLoginEnabledForStore()
    {
        $storeId = $this->_helper->getCurrentStoreId();

        if ($this->_helper->getConfigValue('general/general/forcelogin', $storeId) == true) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

As you see I have added a die statement, but it does not execute when the cached version of page is loaded.

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did you find any solution on this. I also have similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

That predispatch event is not dispatched when loading cached content.

You could plugin to the load method, either before or after.

In di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Cache">
    <plugin name="some-name" type="Vendor\Module\Model\App\PageCachePlugin"/>
</type>
```

In your new class:

```
public function afterLoad(
    \Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Cache $subject,
    $result
) {
    ... //Do something here
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?
What will the plugin of cache will do in my case?

Comment: this way you can check your conditions and perform the redirect before or after loading the content from cache. As you noticed that the event you are targeting doesn't get dispatched when pulling the page content from the cache.

Comment: Will this work for Varnish as well?